# GoDaddy Cron Job issue with Shell and Perl Script

Tags: php, perl, cron, cgi, shellexecute

i created a Cron Job on my GoDaddy Server, named "SponUpdate.sh"

here is the code for this file

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/perl /home/content/14/5959214/html/cgi/JLLoadSponFRJ.pl
/usr/bin/perl /home/content/14/5959214/html/cgi/JLLoadSponMGJ.pl
/usr/bin/perl /home/content/14/5959214/html/cgi/JLLoadSponCAD.pl
/usr/bin/perl /home/content/14/5959214/html/cgi/JLLoadSponCJB.pl
```

Now the issue is when this cron Job Runs it says me following Error,

"/bin/sh: /var/chroot/home/content/14/5959214/html/cgi/SponUpdate.sh: /bin/bash: bad interpreter: Permission denied"

here is the code for one of Perl File  "JLLoadSponFRJ.pl"

```
my $command = '/web/cgi-bin/php5 -q $HOME/html/GISJobs/JLLoadSpon.php';
exec ($command) or print STDERR "couldn't exec $command: $!";
```

i am unable to resolve it from last 3 days,

Please help me,

Thanks in advance,

Regards,

Comment: Seems obvious `...Permission denied`. Contact your administrator.

Comment: i asked godaddy team but its uselessy they asked me to ready there support link Here's a link: What is a Cron Job?.

Comment: Try changing from bash to sh in your script.  Maybe you don't have permissions for bash, but do for sh.

Comment: at this place ? #!/bin/bash 
`#!/bin/bash`
 to 
`#!/bin/sh` ?

Comment: @Shabi - yes that determines which shell is running.

Comment: @CraigTreptow now i am using the following code in my .sh file 
`#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/perl /home/content/14/5959214/html/cgi/JLLoadSponFRJ.pl`

still same error , Permission Denide

Comment: This script has permission to execute (run), right?  chmod +x SponUpdate.sh  If not that, then I think your back to GoDadddy support.

Comment: where should i add this line ? 
`chmod +x SponUpdate.sh`

Comment: @Shabi - that was a command to execute, assuming you have access to a command shell with Go Daddy.

Comment: Try formatting the cron job command like such:
    /bin/bash $HOME/html/example.sh

Answer (score 2):

So you're launching a cron job that runs a bash script that calls some perl scripts that call php.  Why don't you just call php directly from cron?

Check that your bash script does not contain "\r\n" line endings: You might be trying to invoke "/bin/bash\r" instead of "/bin/bash"

Comment: here is my code please check if there is ny \r or \n 

`#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/perl /home/content/14/5959214/html/cgi/JLLoadSponFRJ.pl
/usr/bin/perl /home/content/14/5959214/html/cgi/JLLoadSponMGJ.pl
/usr/bin/perl /home/content/14/5959214/html/cgi/JLLoadSponCAD.pl
/usr/bin/perl /home/content/14/5959214/html/cgi/JLLoadSponCJB.pl`

Comment: actually the reason to not adding PHP script in .sh file is code is on more then 2000 lines and database connection etc

Answer (score 0):

You can check the bash path with

```
which bash
```

and then you can correct the shebang !#/bin/bash of the perl script.

Comment: thanks for your answer, would you please let me know how i can use this script ?
`which bash`

and how i see the response ? becasue i am a PHP developer

Comment: which is a unix program; you need a terminal account to use this program.

Comment: how can i check the unix programe? as i already told you that i am not much familier with UNIX etc

Comment: @shabi: when you type php -v in terminal gives it version number and cli mode support?